# Json asynctask service

Tags: android, android-asynctask, json

конечно же используя http запросы, json, service, asynctask можно оперировать данными как будет нам угодно. Но часто мне не нужны эти расширенные настройки, хочется чего-то быстрого, чтоб было меньше строк кода. Вот случайно наткнулся на сайт [parse](https://parse.com/docs/index)   Хочу спросить у опытных разработчиков, как вы думаете стоит ли пользоваться таким сервисом?  там запись и чтение данных очень простое, также есть push notifications. Просто я работаю дома сам, не у кого набираться опыта. Интересно что именно используют разработчики, какие библиотеки используют и так далее.

Comment: Всё зависит от задачи. Я, например, свою базу данных в одном разрабатываемом приложении вообще на Dropbox храню.
Кстати, сдаётся мне, что на сервис Parse.com ты попал после прочтения документации на Facebook. Они его рекомендуют тем, у кого своего хостинга нет.

Comment: у меня есть хостинг, просто во многом процесс разработки сокращается если пользоваться чем-то подобным